# Understanding butterfly lemma and Isomorphism theorems

Tags: group-theory, intuition, group-isomorphism

This is the lemma in the title: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zassenhaus_lemma

I've been studying isomorphism theorems and I have an intuition on them, and feel that they are quite natural. The motivation for these first theorems is clear, but not for butterfly one. What intuition could ge get for this lemma?  Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: This is used in one proof of the Schreier refinment theorem, although its used can be avoided.

Comment: My memory is that it useful for proving equivalence between composition series for groups with operators, but perhaps it can still be avoided.

Comment: The motivation for this result has already been explained: it is used in the proof of Schreier's refinement theorem. I am not sure what else needs to be said. I have always understood intuition as something personal, which you have to discover for yourself, rather than something that can be explained.

Comment: @DerekHolt Maybe my words caused some misunderstanding. By the term *intuition*, I actually meant the intuition of the name of the lemma, i.e. why we call it butterfly lemma, instead of where this lemma coming from. Maybe *intuition* is not a suitable term. Sorry for the ambiguity caused by my English.

Comment: Oh I see! That's a bit like asking why the constellation Ursa Major (Great Bear in English) is so-called. If you search for images associated with the Butterfly Lemma you will gain some insight into the name!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3857104/understanding-the-proof-and-meaning-of-the-butterfly-lemma-zassenhaus-langs) discussion? I am attaching/quoting the main parts below (with credits). If this is not allowed, please let me know or make the necessary changes (without informing me).

1. **Following is (Serge) Lang's proof (from that page):**
   [image]

2. **Following is user [Tab1e](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/612017/tab1e)'s proof from the [same page](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4450392/1128618):**

   > This answer is based on [https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/.C.to.L/](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Egbergman/.C.to.L/)
   > asserting some of my understandings
   >
   > If $G$ is a group, and $U/u$, $V/v$ are homomorphic images of
   > subgroups of $G$, meaning that there are two surjective
   > homomorphisms(Results of [Fundamental theorem on homomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_on_homomorphisms)):
   > one is from $U$ to $U/u$, and the other one is from $V$ to $V/v$.
   >
   > After the definitions of the objects, one would like to describe the
   > extent to which one can "relate" part of the structure of $U/u$ and
   > part of the structure of $V/v$, based on their common origin in $G$.
   >
   > To find the common "region", one can take the subgroup of $U/u$
   > consisting of all elements which are also images of elements of $V$,
   > which is written this as $u(U \cap V)/u$. Similarly, the analogous
   > subgroup of $V/v$ is $(U \cap V)v/v$.
   >
   > To get a common homomorphic image of these, we must divide each by the
   > subgroup of those elements that are annihilated in the construction of
   > the other. Namely, use $u(U \cap v)$ instead of $u$ in the denumerator
   > and $(u \cap V)v$ instead of $v$ in the respective denumerator.
   >
   > Now, the Butterfly Lemma says that after making these adjustments, we
   > do get isomorphic groups, the "common heritage" of $U/u$ and $V/v$.
   >
   > **Remark**: Group-theorists call a factor-group of a subgroup of a group $G$ a subfactor of $G$. Thus, given two subfactors $U/u$ and
   > $V/v$ of a group $G$, the Butterfly Lemma characterizes their largest
   > natural "common subfactor".

---

P.S. Please do not gift me the bounty even if this answer is helpful.

Comment: Thanks Tommy. That thread is a bit too long and I did miss Lang’s proof in the thread. His graph is clear enough.

Comment: Please do not use pictures of symbols for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched, and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers.